# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - Received when trying to seed data with AdonisJS

Tags: adonis.js

I have changed both files as far as commas and semicolons, both of which have been driving eslint crazy. Nothing seems to appease it within **factory.js** especially, but the odd error messages that I am getting below make me think this may be something else. Anyone have any experience with this?

**UserSeeder.js**

```
const Factory = use('Factory');
const Database = use('Database');

class UserSeeder {
  async run () {

    const user = await Factory
    .model('App/Models/User')
    .create()

    const users = await Database.table('users');
    console.log(users);
  }
}   

module.exports = UserSeeder;
```

**factory.js**

```
const Factory = use('Factory');
const Hash = use('Hash');


Factory.blueprint('App/Models/User', () => {
  return {
    username: 'test',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: await Hash.make('test'),
  } 
});
```

And the lovely and informative error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

1 _preLoadFiles.forEach
  D:\Source\VuePractice\intro-to-vuetify-with- 
  adonis\server\node_modules\@adonisjs\ignitor\src\Ignitor\index.js:375

2 Ignitor._loadPreLoadFiles
  D:\Source\VuePractice\intro-to-vuetify-with- 
  adonis\server\node_modules\@adonisjs\ignitor\src\Ignitor\index.js:367

3 Ignitor.fire
  D:\Source\VuePractice\intro-to-vuetify-with- 
  adonis\server\node_modules\@adonisjs\ignitor\src\Ignitor\index.js:760
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue you have in your code is that you are using the keyword `await` in your Factory for `App/Models/User` and the callback isn't `async`.

It needs to be:

```
const Hash = use('Hash')
const Factory = use('Factory')

Factory.blueprint('App/Models/User', async () => {
  return {
    username: 'test',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: await Hash.make('test'),
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just a typo that I had in my start/routes.js file.

[image: Error on line 24, I accidentally added a 'v' to the end of the line]

It gave me the next error.

[image]

And i solved it removing the extra character. I hope it helps anyone with the same error.